# what does this number(spacing between pads) in the datasheet mean?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-layers, dimensions

i am going to design footprint for a devise and i need to know spacing between pads. do you know what does (2-1.27) mean?[image]
the devise is pico oem socket.

thanks

Comment: '1.27'(mm) is the pitch. Not sure what the '2-' refers to. A link to the datasheet would be handy - it might be something to do with tolerances which would be noted elsewhere on the diagram.

Comment: I think "2" refers to 2 rows, one each side of the device, and 1.27 is the pitch. As a cross-check, 23 * 1.27 = 29.21, the marked dimension between the outer pads.

Comment: Not first time I see this drawing. Mohammad, can you share datasheet please? Cropped picture at the top left seems to be a socket or connector.

Comment: @Anonymous I had the same [deja vu](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265938/should-i-consider-some-parts-in-designing-footprints-that-they-are-not-pads-and)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question might be much easier to answer with access to the datasheet or more information on the component. However, OP prefers to keep silent, [as in his other question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/265938/should-i-consider-some-parts-in-designing-footprints-that-they-are-not-pads-and).

Comment: Seems this one http://www.microhardcorp.com/P2400-accessories.php. Mohammad actually said that *the devise is pico oem socket*. But I can not view datasheet, it requires registration.

Comment: @Anonymous which means Mohammad has registered, and thus probably can simply ask the manufacturer, who'll be happy to help their customers with info that they, but not us, have.

Comment: Excuse me .i couldn't see your comments. My problem actually solved  but i said in comment of @whatroughbeast my downloaded 3d model was not fit to that. And now i find out maybe 3dmodel is not correct. Dear anonymous This devise is oem socket for p900. I should say there isn't any thing in datasheet to help. And i didnt know i can ask microhard corp thanks  marcus.

Comment: 3d models are not always correct. You can clearly see that the dimension between pads is 1.27. Who knows why they put a 2 infront of the the dimension, but they also put a 4x for the center pads so it looks like they are defining the dimensions by including the number of dimensions. This is kind of weird but dimensioning is an art not a science, buy the component, draw the footprint. Print it out on a high DPI printer and see if it maches up. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.27 refers to the pad-to-pad pitch. There are 24 pads per column, so 23 intervals. 23 times 1.27 is 29.21 which is shown below. The "2-" refers to the fact that this spacing occurs in two different places, once on the left column and once on the right. It lets you know that the specification does not apply only to the column shown.

Likewise, the specification for the horizontal row small pad spacing "2-1.27(15x)" shows that 16 pads are involved, and the spacing applies both to the upper and lower rows.

Comment: Yes i guessed it is probably like what you said and i used them in my design but when i downloaded 3d model for that, it seemed to be wrong . I don't know maybe the 3d model i found, is not correct.